# Does $F/N_{1}\cong F/N_{2}$ implies $N_{1}\cong N_{2}$ and vice versa?

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-geometry, free-groups, group-presentation

It would be great for me to see an example of finite group $F$ and two epimorphisms $\varphi_{i}:F\twoheadrightarrow G$ from $F$ onto a group $G$, with $N_{1}\ncong N_{2}$, where $N_{i}=ker\varphi_{i}$, $i=1,2$ (e.g., finite group which contains two non-isomorphic subgroups each of index $2$).

However, I am interested more in the case $F=F(a,b)$ the free group on the set $\{a,b\}$. That is, the case we have two isomorphic presentations $\langle a,b|R_{1}\rangle\cong\langle a,b|R_{2}\rangle$ but with non-isomorphic normal closures $N_{i}=N_{F}(R_{i})$, $i=1,2$. Note that if $G_{1}$ (or $G_{2}$) is finite, then the ranks of $N_{1}$ and $N_{2}$ are equal, so they are isomorphic (since they are free by Nieslen-Schreier).

What about the converse: if $N_{1}\cong N_{2}$ are two isomorphic normal subgroups of the free group $F=F(a,b)$, can we deduce that $F/N_{1}\cong F/N_{2}$?

Thanks.

Comment: The converse is false. We could have $N_1$ and $N_2$ both free of rank $k+1$ and $G/N_1$ and $G/N_2$ any pair of nonisomorphic finite groups of order $k$. But when $G$ is free of rank 2 we have $G/N_1 \cong G/N_2 \Rightarrow N_1 \cong N_2$, because they are borh free of the same rank.

Comment: Here is an interesting follow up question: the Nielsen-Schrier theorem uses the Axiom of Choice to prove that non-finitely generated subgroups of a free group are free. If we do not assume Choice then it is consistent that there are non-free subgroups of free groups. So we can ask: is it consistent for there to exist normal subgroups $N_1, N_2\lhd F(a,b)$ such that $N_1\not\cong N_2$ but $F(a,b)/N_1\cong F(a,b)/N_2$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example, let $G=D_8$ of order $8$, generated by $a$ of order $4$ and $b$ of order $2$. Then $\langle a\rangle$ and $\langle a^2,b\rangle$ are normal subgroups of index $2$, non-isomorphic. (One is cyclic of order $4$, one is Klein four.)

For free groups, every subgroup of a free group is free, so there are three options for $N_1$. It has finite rank, infinite rank, or is trivial. It has finite rank if and only if it has finite index. Thus if $|F/N_1|$ is finite then $F/N_1\cong F/N_2$ implies $N_2$ has finite index.

The rank of $N_i$ is given by a formula in terms of index and number of generators of the free group ($n(d-1)+1$, where $d$ is the number of generators and $n$ the index), and so $N_1\cong N_2$ in this case. If $N_1\cong N_2$ then all you know is that $F/N_1$ and $F/N_2$ have the same order.

If $N_1$ is trivial then $F/N_1\cong F$. As Derek Holt says, this means that $N_2=1$ as $F$ is not isomorphic to a proper quotient of itself.

The final case is when $N_1$ is not finitely generated, or equivalently, $N_1$ has infinite index (and is non-trivial). Then all such $N_i$ are isomorphic (as $F$ is countable).

Thus if $F/N_1\cong F/N_2$ then $N_1\cong N_2$, and if $N_1\cong N_2$ then $F/N_1$ and $F/N_2$ have the same order.

Comment: I think when $G$ is free of rank 2, then $G/N_1 \cong G/N_2 \Rightarrow N_1 \cong N_2$ even when the index is infinite. Since $G$ is Hopfian, $N_1$ and $N_2$ are either both trivial or both nontrivial, and in the second case they are both free of countably infinite rank.

Comment: Normal subgroups of infinite index in free groups are never finitely generated. So in fact $|F/N_1|=|F/N_2|\Leftrightarrow N_1\cong N_2$.

Comment: True. The free subgroups are not normal. I will edit my answer.

Comment: Your edit is incorrect. *Finitely generated* normal subgroups have finite index.

Comment: Thanks. This is what I get for trying to edit with a baby on me.

Comment: @user1729 You mean nontrivial normal subgroups of infinite index in free groups are never finitely generated. This brings back memories of student days long ago when I was docked a mark in a test for making exactly that mistake.

Comment: @Derek Shortly after writing my comment I realised I had missed this, and was wondering if someone would correct me before I returned...(thanks, though.)